# Slow debugging Nodejs with Eclipse

Tags: jquery, node.js, eclipse, jtable, nodeclipse

Has anybody experienced this while debugging a Nodejs application on Eclipse? It takes a whole lot of time to show a page rendered by a jade template that displays the jquery-based jtable from http://jtable.org. Like 30 seconds. I have seen some posts about this issue but none have a definite resolution. It gets so bad that I fall back on debugging with print statements. Any quick tip will be appreciated. I am running with Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

If I don't display the page and go straight to pulling rows from a database and just return a JSON structure then everything is at normal speed.